# uiCalendarConfig.calendars undefined in angular-ui/ui-calendar

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I have taken the latest calendar.js from github for ui-calendar but the below code throws error.

```
$scope.changeView = function(view,calendar) {
uiCalendarConfig.calendars[calendar].fullCalendar('changeView',view);
};
```

Can someone guide me how to resolve the issue?Error is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendars' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

Try naming your calendar eg. `calendar="myCalendar"`

After that you can access it with:
`uiCalendarConfig.calendars["myCalendar"]`

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#accessing-the-calendar-object